# CSS does not work with URLs that have more than 1 parameter (/word/apple does not work)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using Nodejs, Express, MySQL, EJS.

I need to make a URL that looks like this: /nameOfPage/postl

Problem is: /nameOfPage/postl does NOT show the css of the appropriate file, while /nameofPage does work properly. It renders only the HTML and gives this error in the console. `"Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3000/why/word.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."`

I googled the problem and giving the link tag a "type="text/html" DOES remove the error but the CSS is still NOT working. ( I tried with and without the type, I changed the type to css instead of html, and nothing helped)

The part which might be the problem is the URL in the error, "http://localhost:3000/why/word.css", what does the first parameter of the URL have to do with the CSS file? I assume it's trying to read it, but I don't know how to fix it. (I have a "word" EJS and CSS file)

I am getting the page names from MySQL and looping over them and creating the appropriate pages.

(This is the test code I was using)

```
app.get("/why/anele", function(req,res){
    let outsideL =5; 
    let outsideisAuthL =5;
    let outsideUsernameL = 5;
    outsideL = 5;

    let name = 5;
    let title = 5;
    let description = 5;
    let sidebar = 5;
    let submissiontext = 5;
    outsideUsernameL = 5;
    let isAuthenticated = 5;

    res.render("word", {name: name, description: description, sidebar:sidebar, submissiontext:submissiontext, outsideUsernameL:outsideUsernameL, outsideisAuthL:outsideisAuthL, outsideL:outsideL})})
```

Changing "/why/anele" to "/why" does work but I need "/why/anele" to work. (/why/ also does NOT work)

The head of the "word" EJS file.

```
                       <head>
                          <title>This is the Title This is the Title This is the Title</title>
                          <meta name="keywords" content=" vote, comment, submit ">
                          <meta name="description" content="internet">
                          <meta name="referrer" content="origin">
                          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                          <link rel="stylesheet" href="word.css">

                      </head>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you link your css file like this:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="word.css">`

Your server do not understand to look the css file in the root, it searches in the provided route.

For correct this, simply put like this

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/word.css">`